# Equation of a plane parallel on a line

Tags: geometry, vectors, plane-geometry

I need some help:
So: A2 is a plane, I know 1 point ( M(3,-4,2) ) from plane and 1 direction vector ( (2,1,-5) ) (from A1 ) but i need one more direction vector.How can I use that 
parallelism information? I know that normal vector of A2 * director vector of A'1 = 0 (dot product) but how can I use this? 
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvCWl.jpg)

Comment: What is $A1$? And is the point $M$ in the plane $A1$?

Comment: A plane in $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be defined by a point an a line segment, as the plane contain both the point and the segment (endpoints).  A plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be defined by a point and a direction vector as the plane intersecting the point and **perpendicular** to the vector.

Comment: A1, A'1 are lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can find the plane you seek, for example, since $A_1$ is contained in your plane, you can use it to find a vector $v$ defined by two of its points (you can choose them arbitrarily). Then, using $M$ as base point, the vectorial equation of the plane will be $X=M+ \lambda.v + \mu.(2,1,-5)$.

Of course you can get around this in other ways, but this one will do the trick.

Comment: I tried to create a vector from two points from A1 put I obtained (2,-1,5) same direction vector

Comment: Ok. The next vector can be chosen from $A'_1$ being parallel. The vector is $(4,7,2)$ if I didn't miscalculate.

Comment: Why can I use vector from A'1? If a plane is parallel with a line then they have director vectos common?

Comment: Of course. It comes from the fact that if $S$ is linearly independent then $v$ is parallel to the subspace spanned by $S$ iff $S \cup v$  is linearly dependent. Which in turn implies you can take that exact same vector.